Hiding Database URL on python(compiled with pyinstaller)
I have a program I'm currently developing, and it uses MONGODB. I heard that if you compile this program with PYINSTALLER, you can decompile it. If someone decompiled my program, the DB URL is immediately exposed. Is there a way to prevent this?
(Sorry I'm using a translator right now so it can be wrong)


No way to prevent this, because with effort they can get to something that you've provided them with, as you gave them the program with all the information needed to connect to the target mongodb. Best you can do is obfuscate, which will slow them down, see the linked threads.
